# How to return a 404 error for non-existent page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, http-status-codes

I am working on a .NET/C# documentation web app. When a link on the website is clicked it fetches the document by name and displays the page.

The process is these document names have spaces in them, so when a link on the website is clicked the request replaces spaces with %20 while sending. That request url is being stripped off of the %20 to get the actual document name with spaces on the backend.

The problem is if I type in the document name on the url without spaces it's giving me internal error instead of 404 error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Eg:

- Document Name: Installation Prereq.md
- Actual URL: `/home/documentation/Installation%20Prereq.md` --> this successfully returns the doc

But,

- Error URL: `/home/documentation/InstallationPrereq.d` --> this returns
  500 error, I would like to set this upto 404 error, as there is no
  document with such a name.

Comment: have a try-catch where you get 500 exceptions and then send response as 404.

Comment: You should share your action method code.

Comment: Your file extension is different between the two examples as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET throws an exception when you try to access/return a file that does not exist. This exception is catched by IIS (if your application does not handle it) which returns a HTTP response with `500` status code.

The solution would be to check if the file exists, ie `File.Exists("folder/filename")`

And if it returns `false`, let it know to your controller's action, which it turns can return a response with `404` status code:

```
public ActionResult ControllerAction(string filename)
{
    var theFile = TryFindFile(filename, out fileFound);

    if (fileFound == false)
        return new HttpNotFoundResult(); // this returns a HTTP response with 404 status code

    return theFile;
}
```